# Background color not changing in Chrome when mouse up

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events

I have 4 buttons in a page out of 4 one button is multi select button (like selection box). When I mouse over the color of the button will change and while mouse out the color of the button will change to normal. But if I click on the multiselect button the color is changing (which is fine) and it shows the data like dropdown but, if I `mousehover` to other button then the color of the multiselect button is not changing to normal, this happens only in Chrome and in IE11 it is working fine.

Below is my code:

```html
 <div id="ButtonDiv" class="btn"><a class="btn-a-normal" id="MORE_ACT"  onmousedown="BtnUtilities.buttonDown(this)" onmouseup="BtnUtilities.buttonUp(this)" onmouseleave="BtnUtilities.buttonUp(this)" onmouseout="BtnUtilities.buttonUp(this)" onselectstart="return false"  href="javascript:void(0)" data-href="javascript:void(0)">
```

```js
    var BtnUtilities = {
        buttonDown: function(element) {
            element.className = "btn-a-pressed";
        },
    
        buttonUp: function(element) {
            element.className = "btn-a-normal";
        }
    };
```

```css
    .btn > a.btn-a-normal > div.btn-border, .buttonOn > a.btn-a-normal > div.btn-border {
      border-style: solid ;
      border-width: 1px ;
      border-color: #c7c7c7 #c7c7c7 #c7c7c7 #c7c7c7 ;
    }
    
    .btn > a.btn-a-pressed > div.btn-border, .buttonOn > a.btn-a-pressed > div.btn-border {
      border-style: solid ;
      border-width: 1px ;
      border-color: #4b4b4b #4b4b4b #4b4b4b #4b4b4b ;
    }
```

Could you please let me know where I am wrong?

Comment: must be something missing. Your code produces nothing visible ... also, the title says something about the background, but the css only effect the border

Comment: `ButtonUtilities` is not the same thing as as `BtnUtilities`

Comment: there's also no div with class btn-border inside the `<a>` ... so not sure what IE is doing other than predicting what you intended

Comment: Sorry, I missed to update btnutilities. I have some additional css for this but I provided only the above. My problem is it is working in IE but not in chrome even simple border color change.

Answer (score 0):

check this simple code which help you

```
<div id="ButtonDiv" class="btn"><a class="btn-a-normal" id="MORE_ACT"  onmouseover="buttonDown(this)" onmouseout="buttonUp(this)">test</a>
</div>

<script>

    function buttonDown(element) {
        element.className = "btn-a-pressed";
    }

    function buttonUp(element) {
        element.className = "btn-a-normal";
    }

</script>

<style>
    .btn > a.btn-a-normal {
        color: red;
    }

    .btn > a.btn-a-pressed {
        color: green;
    }
</style>
```